# Send contact form results to google drive spreadsheet

Tags: 7, emails

Is it possible, after form submission (Webform), that the data is immediately sent to spread-sheet in `Google drive` or some kind of similar application?

Simple fields like :
date, time, first name, last name, webform title.

Answer (score 1):

There is a module that claims to do so (I haven't used it myself but this would be a good starting point): [Webform to Google Docs](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_to_gdocs)

> This module inserts Webform submissions as new rows in a Google Docs spreadsheet. In the future it may handle updating of entries as well as saving submissions into "docs" as well as "spreadsheets".